# Directory cannot be added to zip archive

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I would like to add a directory (`CLIENT_PATH`) to an existing zip archive which is wordpress.zip. All subdirectories and files within should be added to the following path of my zip archive: `wp-content/themes/{new directory comes here}`

When I run the following script, I will get no errors but also the files are not added to the theme directory of my zip archive.

```
define('CLIENT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp_theme/clients_templates/' . $_POST['title']);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('wordpress.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob(CLIENT_PATH . "/*") as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file, 'wordpress/wp-content/themes');
}
$zip->close();
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try with "/*.*" instead of "*"

Comment: @kannan I tried. Still nothing added to the zip archive.

Comment: Enable error report and try it,you may got problem

Comment: @kannan I am using `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`. and I don't get any errors. The page is getting loaded normally (Status code: 200 OK). So I don't see any problems.

Comment: Good,inside for each just print_r($file).It will display whether object contains file or empty

Comment: @kannan this returns the path of all my files:  `/home/pomcanys/public_html/wp_theme/clients_templates/dssdf/404.php/home/pomcanys/public_html/wp_theme/clients_templates/dssdf/archive.php ....`